# TempData is empty after JS redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save to TempData in my CheckOutController and then redirect to another View (OrderCompleted), but the TempData after the redirection is empty. The redirection is made using JS Code.

When the form is submitted I am validating the details with the following code and then redirecting to 'OrderCompleted'.

```
 $('#paymentDetails > form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        /* I am validating some details here... */

            window.location.replace("/OrderCompleted/");
        });
    });
```

I understand that TempData is not pass when using JS redirection, is this correct?

What would be the best way to transfer the data? It's only a small string.

Thanks.

Comment: TempData uses Session. Is it disabled?

Comment: No, I am passing TempData in other controller when the redirection is made from the controller. From JS redirection is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this 'small string' as query string parameter.